# How to unsubscribe from DatagramSocket MessageReceived event

Tags: sockets, windows-runtime, udp, unsubscribe

I'm trying to unsubscribe from MessageReceived on the bound UDP socket (DatagramSocket) and getting the exception.
That is how I register:

```
    EventRegistrationToken myRegToken;
    myRegToken = (mySocket->MessageReceived += ref new TypedEventHandler<DatagramSocket^, 
          DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs^>(listenerContext, &ListenerContext::OnMessage));
```

This is how I unregister:

```
mySocket->MessageReceived -= myRegToken;
```

And I get an Exception: **A method was called at an unexpected time.**

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No luck, the only solution seems to delete mySocket with `mySocket = nullptr;` and recreate it if needed

Comment: Please, note that DatagramSocket is IDisposable so you should call Dispose before mySocket = nullptr

Answer (score 0):

Just use

`Socket.Dispose();`

It's the official way, described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241358

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the socket.